# Hosting statistic tool on heroku with flask secure?

Tags: web-application, python

I am working on a statistic tool for our company, millions of datasets. Now I need to upload the project, so all company members can request data from everywhere.

I am working with Python 3/Flask and I plan to upload the project on heroku.

Heroku offers by default an SSL certificate (I do not plan to use a custom domain).

In addition I integrated [Flask-BasicAuth](https://flask-basicauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask.ext.basicauth.BasicAuth.check_credentials). It works on localhost fine, one can only access the website if the username and password are known.

I also use [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and a `CRSF` token on the form. After the from submits, which is a must, I request different statistics via AJAX.

1. User enters a daterange
2. User submits form and the basic dataset is selected
3. Different statistics are requested via `AJAX POST`

Step 3. means I have a lot of routes, which only accept a `POST` method and return a `JSON` object.

This tool MUST be only accessible by company members, because important data can be requested and seen. Does my approach sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP basic auth is prone to be bruteforced. [Flask-HTTPAuth](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with digest mode could be a better solution, but there are also several security concerns to be resolved, as well as additional password and lockout policies.

Another approach colud be integration with trusted Oauth provider like [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). This way you just shift authentication-related responsibilities to 3rd party that you can trust, and it could be much easier yet reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am also thinking to add more security layers, for example allow requests only from a certain city. But all in all every system can be hacked if targeted specifically. Maybe that is generally a bad idea to upload such a tool on a live server. I am thinking about adding a functionality to download all the stats as a PDF

Comment: Would you upload such a tool on a live server or would you search an other option?

Comment: An other idea is to install this tool on the PC's of other company members, so everyone has a local version and everyone would be able to run it from localhost.

Comment: Yes, I'd upload such tool on a live server after at least: 
- successfull verification of tool with OWASP ASVS checklist; 
- enabling 2FA for all users;
- establishing a regular monitoring of a hosting regarding data breaches.
Regarding localhosts - your data will be as secure as every laptop of your company.